# Show login or register to anonymous user fro flag

Tags: panels, flags

I created flag for nodes and trying to show a login or register link to anonymous users instead of the flag button on a node page (panels). A redirect to the signup form would be ok as well. I tried the [Flag anonymous](https://www.drupal.org/project/flag_anon) module but it doesn't work for some reasons.

Are there any other ways to realize this functionality?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question correctly:

- You should be able, through permissions, to restrict access to the Flags, so that anonymous users don't see it
- you could use the default user login block, or create a custom one that redirects users, and place that block in the same position as the Flags, with a message like "To Flag objects, you must first login" and then restrict that block to show only to anonymous users